# Is it possible to Use HTML inside a (React) Three.js Decal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

> I've also asked [this question on Three.js Discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-use-html-inside-a-react-three-js-decal/60260).

In [this docs CodeSandbox example by drcmda](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/using-decals-ymb5d9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A13%2C19), I would like to make the text decal a bit richer, with HTML. For example, adding something like this right below the `<Text>`:

```
<Html rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} fontSize={4} color="white">
  <h1 style={{ color: 'orange' }}>hello from HTML</h1>
</Html>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The example goes from this:

[image: drcmda's Decal Bunny]

To this:

[image: drcmda's Decal Bunny with <Html>]

The `<Html>` component isn't properly positioned and doesn't follow the correct perspective at all, it's as if it were effectively not attached to the object.

Is there a way of making this work? I thought `<Text>` and `<Html>` would work similary...

---

Just for reference, in case the sandbox link get's broken, here's drcmda's code:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { suspend } from 'suspend-react'
import {
  useGLTF,
  useCursor,
  useTexture,
  Text,
  Decal,
  Environment,
  OrbitControls,
  RenderTexture,
  RandomizedLight,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  AccumulativeShadows,
  Html
} from '@react-three/drei'

const bunny = import('@pmndrs/assets/models/bunny.glb')

export const App = () => (
  <Canvas shadows camera={{ position: [-5, 5, 10], fov: 15 }}>
    <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
    <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
    <pointLight position={[-10, -5, -10]} />
    <group position={[0, -0.75, 0]}>
      <Bun position={[0, 0.9, 0]} />
      <AccumulativeShadows frames={80} color="black" opacity={1} scale={12} position={[0, 0.04, 0]}>
        <RandomizedLight amount={8} radius={5} ambient={0.5} position={[5, 5, -10]} bias={0.001} />
      </AccumulativeShadows>
    </group>
    <Environment preset="city" resolution={512} />
    <OrbitControls makeDefault />
  </Canvas>
)

function Bun(props) {
  const textRef = useRef()
  const [pmndrs, react, three] = useTexture(['/pmndrs.png', '/react.png', '/three.png'])
  const { nodes } = useGLTF(suspend(bunny).default)
  useFrame((state) => (textRef.current.position.x = Math.sin(state.clock.elapsedTime) * 5.5))
  return (
    <mesh castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.mesh.geometry} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <meshStandardMaterial color="black" roughness={0} metalness={0.5} />
      <Decal position={[0, 0, 0.75]} rotation={[-0.4, Math.PI, 0]} scale={[0.9, 0.25, 1]}>
        <meshStandardMaterial roughness={0.6} transparent polygonOffset polygonOffsetFactor={-10}>
          <RenderTexture attach="map" anisotropy={16}>
            <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault manual aspect={0.9 / 0.25} position={[0, 0, 5]} />
            <color attach="background" args={['#af2040']} />
            <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
            <directionalLight position={[10, 10, 5]} />
            <Text rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} ref={textRef} fontSize={4} color="white">
              hello from drei
            </Text>
            <Html rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} fontSize={4} color="white">
              <h1 style={{ color: 'orange' }}>hello from HTML</h1>
            </Html>
            <Dodecahedron />
          </RenderTexture>
        </meshStandardMaterial>
      </Decal>
      <Decal position={[-0.7, 0.55, 0.3]} rotation={[1, 0, Math.PI]} scale={0.2} map={pmndrs} map-anisotropy={16} />
      <Decal position={[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]} rotation={0} scale={0.25} map={react} map-anisotropy={16} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Dodecahedron(props) {
  const meshRef = useRef()
  const texture = useTexture('/react.png')
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false)
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false)
  useCursor(hovered)
  useFrame((state, delta) => (meshRef.current.rotation.x = meshRef.current.rotation.y += delta))
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={meshRef}
      scale={clicked ? 2.25 : 1.75}
      onClick={() => click(!clicked)}
      onPointerOver={() => hover(true)}
      onPointerOut={() => hover(false)}>
      <dodecahedronGeometry args={[0.75]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'goldenrod'} />
      <Decal position={[0, -0.2, 0.5]} scale={0.75} map={texture} map-anisotropy={16} />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't think so that is possible, because `Html` is _DOM only_ component, I was trying some experements with attaching geometry, but not success... Even when you switch here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/the-three-graces-forked-348jg9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A70%2C30 to `boxGeometry` then you will get wrong result. Probably `Text` create 3D mesh so it possible attach to 3D environment, but I am not sure about that...

Comment: The legendary @drcmda [helped me with this on Three.js Discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-use-html-inside-a-react-three-js-decal/60260/4). Basically, `<Html>` is not a part of the 3D canvas, it's an overlay, it can't warp on anything within the canvas. You have to use `<Text>` and basically reinvent HTML from it, I guess. I wonder why the pmndrs guys haven't added helpers for that on Drei.

Comment: Oh, now I read Paul's answer on forum 3, so as I thought: "_...html lives on top of the canvas..._".

Comment: PS. I have seen on your YT that you rolling in bjj... So maybe some day will be occasion to spar :) BTW I was playing a little bit with r3f and https://bjj.hahhar.com/

Comment: Nice effects! And nice competence-consciousness matrix! Believe it or not, I had first heard of that concept when reading psychology books and playing Go. But then realized it's applicable everywhere, like in BJJ. I kinda stopped with BJJ though unfortunately (after practicing for 3 years), almost lost a tooth with and that was traumatizing enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the legendary [@drcmda or @0xca0a](https://github.com/drcmda) in [this comment](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-use-html-inside-a-react-three-js-decal/60260/4), the `<Html>` component is actually outside the 3D canvas, the only thing making it change its perspective is CSS 3D transformations.

As it is outside the `<canvas>`, it cannot warp on top of objects within it, so it's not possible to put `<Html>` inside a `<Decal>`.

However, you can do that with `<Text>`. And, if you want richer, HTML-like behavior from that plain text, then you'll basically have to reinvent HTML functionalities from there. Personally, I don't know why [Pmndrs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/) hasn't implemented that kind of thing within [Drei](https://docs.pmnd.rs/), but that's the state of things, I guess.